# Fiddler composer tab - Decode request

Tags: http, composer-php, fiddler

This request is responding with HTTP 500. When I click on the "Request body is encoded. Click to decode", drag the request to the composer tab and execute it, I am getting a successful response HTTP 200. The only difference is this: The number 1713 or whatever gets removed after decoding and the request goes through.

What is that 1713 or number that gets added? It is related to encoding/decoding. What could be different in the request?

[image]

Comment: What is "this request"? How is your problem related to Composer?

Comment: Please check the request headers which compression is used on the request. May be a compression is used the server does not support, that would explain the HTTP 500.